# Bottom TabLayout comes on top of keyboard

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

In the app I am designing I have a bottom `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` on my `MainActivity`.

The problem is that each time I click on something that requires input (so the keyboard comes up), that TabLayout sticks to the top of the Keyboard. I would like it to stay where it is - this means it will be hidden by the keyboard.

The problem is expressed in this screenshot. I don't wait it to go to the top of the keyboard.

[image]

**My manifest file is here (I have tried various combinations of `adjustNothing`, `adjustPan`, `adjustResize`...):**

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:name=".PinUpApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/pinup"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/pinup_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.HorecaActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.HorecaMainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.EditProfileActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.PersonProfileActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.RegisterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.NoNetworkActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**And here below is the code for the activity:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@color/white">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:windowActionModeOverlay="false"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ro.ineedhelp.pinup.Utils.NonSwipeableViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIconTint="@color/grey_600"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/grey_600"/>
</FrameLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/sheet_activity_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior" />
```

Comment: Please don't use the design tag; it's in the process of being removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, for your Main Activity in you manifest file.

android:windowSoftInputMode=" stateAlwaysHidden | adjustPan "